# OpenGL GLFW application - client side memory limit

Tags: c++, c, opengl, memory-management, glfw

I work on Windows 10 x64. 32 bit processes can use up to 2GB memory. I have tested it: a simple program which only allocates 25mb blocks of memory can use ~1950mb of the memory. After exceeding that size malloc returns null. I have created a simple OpenGL application using GLFW library. It just display an empty window - task manager shows that memory usage is about 26 mb. I have noticed that when I try to perform malloc test after calling the following functions:

```
glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

if (!glfwInit())
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "LegacyGL", NULL, NULL);

if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSwapInterval(1);
```

malloc return null when an application memory usage is about **1600mb**. I haven't analyzed GLFW source code but how it is possible ? Before performing malloc test memory usage is about 24mb. Is it possible that task manager doesn't show all memory already used by the program.

**Edit:**

After reducing malloc size the program is able to allocate about 1800mb. It looks like the opengl driver maps some memory region of the program but a task manager doesn't show it. Do you know any tool which allow to check how many memory has been mapped by the driver ? Which OpenGL functions increase such mapped memory region ?

Comment: This is possible because of address space fragmentation (no contiguous 24mb block). When `malloc` returns null keep retrying allocations with ever decreasing block sizes until you get a successful allocation - repeat.  Have a sensible lower limit say 4K (or platform page-size).

Comment: So it looks like GLFW lib causes such significant memory fragmentation.

Comment: Not certain; so just a comment.  The above test is not too difficult to code so you can prove (or disprove) it for yourself.

Comment: Another culprit might be the OpenGL implementation of your video driver. Typically it needs to map some memory regions to communicate with the hardware.

Comment: @Botje please see Edit

Comment: @Irbis I do not think it is the fault of specific OpenGL functions. The OpenGL implementation just has to reserve this space so the driver can transfer buffers, textures and commands via DMA, but also to map GPU buffers in main memory. As another example, you ask for an OpenGL 2.1 context that supports the OpenGL immediate mode. It is very likely that your implementation allocates memory for storing immediate mode commands until you call `glFlush`, at which point the entire bundle is sent to the GPU to interpret.

Comment: To be honest, this entire discussion is academic. There is no good reason to write 32bit software in 2019, especially not if it runs up to the 2GB limit. If you _really_ just need a tiny bit more memory, you can enable the ["large address aware" flag](https://helloacm.com/large-address-aware/), but it is far less effort to just compile for 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2GB limit for 32-bit programs is *address space*. It is a limit for the *number of memory addresses you can have*.

Task Manager displays *actual memory used*.

It is possible - and fairly common - to use up addresses without actually using up memory. For example, the driver might allocate addresses for a big chunk of graphics card memory, even though it's not using any memory yet.

---

Alternatively, it could be that memory was allocated, but it's not a type that Task Manager displays. I'm not sure which type of memory is displayed in the "Processes" tab, but if you go to the "Details" tab you should see that the column is actually called "Memory (active private working set)". If you move the mouse over that, the tooltip says "*the amount of physical memory in used by the process that can't be used by other processes.*"

This is more specific than you might think at first:

- If the memory is shared with any other processes, it's not counted.
- If the memory is currently on disk (not in physical RAM), it's not counted.
- If the memory has been allocated but not accessed yet, it's not counted. In this case it's not in physical RAM, but it's not on disk either because the OS knows there's no point storing blank memory.

---

In summary, there are plenty of reasons why this discrepancy might happen. If you need to use lots of memory, compile your program as 64-bit.

Comment: Which OpenGL functions may increase such mapped memory region ?

Comment: @Irbis all of them